# python search key and read line after matching and send to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have file output like below

```
some junk text
ignore above text
pen: 4
apple: 10
orange: 20
pen: 30
apple: 40
bat: 20
ball: 300
football: 500
pencil: 200
again junk test ignore it
```

Requirement:

Search keyword in file and send next 10 lines output to list1 as values

I tried below code but not working. Need your help to achieve results.

```
from itertools import islice
list1 = []
with open ("file.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith("ignore above text"):
            list1 = (islice(fin,9))
            print list1
```

Expected output:

```
 list1 = ['pen: 4','apple: 10','orange: 20',pen: 30','apple: 40','bat: 20','ball: 300', 'football: 500', 'pencil']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to a list (or a tuple):

```
list1 = list((islice(fin,9)))
#         ^
```

Otherwise it is just a generator which gives you the next value if asked. However, you might as well stick to the generator and iterate over it afterwards:

```
for item in list1:
    print(item.strip())
    # or anything else
```

So your code might become:

```
from itertools import islice
with open("test.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('ignore above text'):
            for item in islice(fp, 9):
                print(item.strip())
```

Generators are an extremely useful and often used mechanism in `Python`, you might want to [**read sth. about them here**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
file_with_data = open("file.txt", "r")
raw_data = file_with_data.read()
file_with_data.close()

input_data_as_list = raw_data.split("\n")
output_data = []
for i in range(len(input_data_as_list)):
    if input_data_as_list[i] == "ignore above text":
        output_data = input_data_as_list[i+1:i+10]
        break

print(output_data)
```

Comment: Better use `with open...`

Comment: Why? I have always preffered to have more control over deciding when to close the file.

Comment: Imo, the code is clearer, more effective and fewer lines are needed: https://ideone.com/hoW9XR Additionally, you **do** have control: the file is not closed until you exit `with`

Comment: True, but this one requires you to exit `with` statement. This way you are forced to create your logic inside. And no, code is not clearer IMO. I rather open file, read and close it as soon as possible instead of waiting for leave `with`. But I guess it depends on the programmer...

Answer (score 0):

```
 mystr=open("your\\file\\path").read()
 my_list=mystr.split("\n")
 my_list=[item for item in my_list if not item.startswith("ignore")]
```